# match array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this:

```
[a] => Array
    (
        [w] => 90
        [h] => 90       
    )

[b] => Array
    (
        [w] => 40
        [h] => 25         
    )
```

And:

```
[a] => Array
    (
        [w] => 90
        [h] => 90    
        [name]  => test
    )

[b] => Array
    (
        [w] => 40
        [h] => 25         
        [name]  => test2
    )
```

How can I find out if the W and H elements from the 1st array match the ones from the second one, and if they do get the `name` value of the matched element ?

Comment: no, I have just two, but they are multi dimensional

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// $arrayWithNamesInIt is the array with w, h, and name
// $array1 is the array with only w and h

$names = array(); // Will hold the names of matching entries
foreach ($arrayWithNamesInIt as $key => $values) {
    if (isset($array1[$key]) && $values['w'] == $array1[$key]['w'] && $values['h'] == $array1[$key]['h']) {
        $names[] = $values['name'];
    }
}
```

([demo](http://www.ideone.com/TTEYF))